# Is Google Cloud Compute Engine separate from Google Cloud SQL

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-sql

I'm really confused if cloud SQL already is included with a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Cloud SQL does not include a VM.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, Cloud SQL is run in virtual instances, but you can't access them in any way.

You could use pure VM instances from Compute Engine to run your own MySQL DB if there's a reason for you that need such level of control over the underlying system.